# How to disable `site.ENABLE_USER_SITE` for an environment?

Tags: python

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/site.html#site.ENABLE_USER_SITE):

> `site.ENABLE_USER_SITE`
>
> Flag showing the status of the user site-packages directory. `True` means that it is enabled and was added to `sys.path`. `False` means that it was disabled by user request (with `-s` or `PYTHONNOUSERSITE`). None means it was disabled for security reasons (mismatch between user or group id and effective id) or by an administrator.

I'm particularly interested in the phrase *or by an administrator*. On machines on which I'm an administrator (i.e. my own), how do I disable this option globally, for a specific interpreter executable?

The reason I want to do this is that new conda environments leave this enabled: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/448

Comment: what did you end up going with?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The value of that variable is determined entirely in [Python code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/44c690112d96a81fe02433de7900a4f8f9457012/Lib/site.py#L214-L236):

```
def check_enableusersite():
    """Check if user site directory is safe for inclusion

    The function tests for the command line flag (including environment var),
    process uid/gid equal to effective uid/gid.

    None: Disabled for security reasons
    False: Disabled by user (command line option)
    True: Safe and enabled
    """
    if sys.flags.no_user_site:
        return False

    if hasattr(os, "getuid") and hasattr(os, "geteuid"):
        # check process uid == effective uid
        if os.geteuid() != os.getuid():
            return None
    if hasattr(os, "getgid") and hasattr(os, "getegid"):
        # check process gid == effective gid
        if os.getegid() != os.getgid():
            return None

    return True
```

The first test is simply for the `-s` switch or the `PYTHONNOUSERSITE` environment variable having been used.

What remains is the tests that return `None` if the effective userid or groupid differ from the process userid or groupid.

An administrator can [set the effective user id or group id bits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid), at which point the effective user of the executable is changed to the owner or group of the executable rather than the user executing Python, at which point the above function will return `None`.

Other than that, a `sitecustomize.py` package could set the value to `None` again, and explicitly remove user directories from the path again. If so, the `usercustomize.py` import step is skipped.

Comment: Yeah, I saw this. The docs seem to imply there's a another way: "None means it was disabled for security reasons (mismatch between user or group id and effective id) *or* by an administrator.". That implies there's another way besides changing the user/group id.

Comment: @ontologist: the above implementation is what is actually going to happen. Since setting the effective user / group bits is an administrator action, I think that is what the documentation is (ineffectively) alluding to.

Comment: Yes, that may be the case. Although, none of these solutions is very convenient. Environment variables are not interpreter-specific, always using a command-line flag is fragile, and changing the user/group id has other effects.

Comment: Ah, saw your edit. That may be the only way to go. Annoying that just setting the value to `None` isn't enough, and you would have to explicitly edit `sys.path`.

Comment: @ontologist: you'd check what `site.getusersitepackages()` returns and remove that path again.

Comment: @MartijnPieters With the sitecustomize strategy to "fix" the environment do we potentially still need to worry that *.pth files in the user directory have already been executed?

Comment: @Robert: No. `.pth` files are processed in `addsitedir()`, which is [only called for the user directory if `ENABLE_USER_SITE` is true](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/44c690112d96a81fe02433de7900a4f8f9457012/Lib/site.py#L315-L316).

Comment: I am calling check_enableusersite() outright with a True value returned (because I did attempt by creating a user site) and yet ENABLE_USER_SITE is False. Working within venv in our current future seems now seems to affect ENABLE_USER_SITE above and beyond check_enableusersite()... 

Comment: A [really good SO reference on _customizing_ virtual environments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54367842/2973538) thoroughly written up by [@pmav99](https://stackoverflow.com/users/592289/pmav99).

Answer (score 8):

Basically you can add the environment variable `PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1` (just set it to something)

So if need to change it globally add this to the `.bashrc` or whatever you use.

for conda:

You can specify variables that will be set for the specific environment [see link](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#set-env-vars)
in short:

```
conda env config vars set PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1
```

and then reactivate your env

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issues where user accidentally installed packages in `~/.local/lib/python3.x/site-packages` with `pip install --user <package>` and that broke their venv.

Found 3 ways to ignore local packages.

1. Set the environment variable `PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1` before starting the interpreter
2. Start the interpreter with the [-s flag](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-s) `python -s ...`
3. Patch `ENABLE_USER_SITE = None` to `ENABLE_USER_SITE = False` in the `.../lib/site.py`

Source code: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/site.py#L82

```
# Enable per user site-packages directory
# set it to False to disable the feature or True to force the feature
ENABLE_USER_SITE = None
```

Judging by the comment, I believe this is meant to be patchable.
`sed -i 's/^ENABLE_USER_SITE = None/ENABLE_USER_SITE = False/g' .../lib/python${PYTHON_VERSION}/site.py`

Answer (score 0):

NOTE:  this is in the reverse direction, to **retroactively enable** the global site package **after creating one particular venv where I forgotten to do so.**

Maybe not exactly what the question asks for, but this was the closest Google got when I searched for a way to flip it back on.

No hacks with site.py required.

---

I had to do this in the reverse direction on Python 3.12.  I typically build my dev environments with just what the work requires, but rely on the global site package to provide utility packages for tooling or code introspection.

(best practices?  probably not, but I am used to it)

In this case, to test the 3.11 to 3.12 I built a venv, installed from the project's requirements.txt and... realized I had forgotten the `--system-site-package` switch.

Anyways...

## tree is a utility to show dir contents.

`tree testyessite/ -L 1`

```
testyessite/
├── bin
├── include
├── lib
└── pyvenv.cfg
```

And in `pyvenv.cfg` I found this interesting flag:

```
include-system-site-packages = true
```

So, basically flip `include-system-site-packages` to `true` to enable the global packages, `false` to disable it, as per this question.