# how to reuse global site-packages in conda env

Tags: python, virtualenv, anaconda

I have a project called `ABC`, I have a conda env just for it in the fold `~/anaconda/envs/ABC`, I believe it is a venv, and I want to use some specific packages from the global site packages.

For normal Python installation it can be done be removing the no-global-site-package.txt from the venv folder, or by setting the venv to use global-site-packages, but I didn't find any equivalent approach to do this in Anaconda. The online documentation does not have answer either.

How to do this for Anaconda?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case anyone is coming back to this now, for conda 4.7.12, entering `export PYTHONNOUSERSITE=True` before the `conda activate` call successfully isolated the conda environment from global/user site packages for me.

On the other hand, entering `export PYTHONNOUSERSITE=0` allows the conda environment to be reintroduced to the global/user site packages.

Note: This is instead of the previously suggested `export PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1`.

Answer (score 5):

you cannot do this explicitly in conda, where the principle is that envs are entirely separate.

**but** the current default behavior of `conda` is to allow **all** global user site-packages to be seen from within environments, as mentioned [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25584276/how-to-disable-site-enable-user-site-for-an-environment). so, the default behavior will allow you to do as you wish, but there is no way to allow only "some specific" global packages as requested.

this behavior has caused [one](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/394) or [two](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/3162) issues. to avoid it,  `export PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1` before `source activate <your env>`. note that the devs are planning to change the default behavior to set `PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1` in 4.4.0 (per the second issue linked).

Comment: I have conda 4.5.8 and `export PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1` before `source activate` didn't do anything for me, it still has all global libraries :(

Comment: I can't reproduce user citynorman's issue. with conda 4.5.11 on windows, the following did not include global libs in the `tmp` env   `conda list > /tmp/global.txt;
  conda create -n tmp python=3.6;
  PYTHONUSERSITE=1 source activate tmp;
  conda list > /tmp/local.txt;
  diff /tmp/global.txt /tmp/local.txt # files differ`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the PYTHONPATH environment variable. For example

```
export PYTHONPATH="/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"
```

would give every environment access to all the libraries in the anaconda distribution. Sort of defeats the purpose of environments though. And if you then want access to a library you installed with home-brew as well, you would add

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/Cellar/another_package/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: Well Dominick, can you explain yourself?