# Import error -- Python looking in wrong $PATH order

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, python-import, package-managers

I'm trying to switch from Homebrew Python to Anaconda Python.
My $PATH is: 
`234:~ user$ echo $PATH
/Users/user/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin`  
Also, when I check `which python`, `which pip`, and `which conda` I get the anaconda directory for all three. But I still get the following when I try to import some standard package (which is installed in the anaconda directory): 
`234:~ user$ python
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:05:08) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
'>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<'stdin>", line 1, in 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/init.py", line 142, in <'module> ... 

ImportError:
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy. If you're working with a numpy git repo, try git clean -xdf (removes all files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.`

I have tried a reboot and completely uninstalling anaconda and reinstalling, all to no avail.  Why is python still using my `usr/local/lib` directory to hunt for packages?  How do I redirect it to the anaconda directory?

Comment: Do you have the `$PYTHONPATH` environment variable set anywhere (e.g. in your `.bash_profile`)?

Comment: $PYTHONPATH is not set.

Comment: What is the output of `python -c import sys; print sys.path`?

Comment: ['', '/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python27.zip', '/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7', '/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Users/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages',  ...]

Comment: This is likely the same issue in question: [https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/448](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/448). That said, all of the solutions I'm seeing sound dicey. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25584276/5054877